# Trouble running 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' on WSL on Windows 10

Tags: .net, .net-core

I am working with .NET and I am working with web applications, and I am typing the command "dotnet dev-certs https --trust", and unfortunately, it is only giving me this response... "Specify --help for a list of available options and commands."

I have tried installing both .NET 2.1, and .NET 2.2, due to some users in other websites saying that it works with .NET 2.1. And unfortunately, there has been no luck whatsoever.

What I was expecting was the Security Warning prompt that I was supposed to get asking me if I should install this certificate. But it doesn't show, instead it just shows me that "Specify --help for a list of available options and commands." Lots of help appreciated.

Comment: What system are you running? To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only). For establishing trust on other platforms refer to the platform specific documentation.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.

Comment: I’m running Linux but it’s the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: check this manual for  Windows Subsystem for Linux, there are special commands instead of --trust https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#trust-https-certificate-from-windows-subsystem-for-linux

Comment: I got the same response "Specify --help ...". I found I had a typo. First see if you have the dev-certs command by typing "dotnet dev-certs -h"